# Best practice for implementation equals and hashcode

Tags: java, spring, jpa, equals, lombok

I've revealed that @Data annotation in Lombok is bad practice now when we use JPA https://dzone.com/articles/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong

So what is the best practice for implementation of these methods for class like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    private String value;
}
```

Maybe this variant?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o))
            return false;
        User that = (User) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
}
```

And implementation such methods by manual require test coverage. Are there some automation possibilities? Maybe this one? https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/

Comment: Are you asking about automated testing of `.equals (Object o)` and of `hashCode()`? Or automated generation of those methods? if the latter, check your IDE for a tool that will generate those two methods.

Comment: I'm asking about correct implementations of these methods. It doesn't make sense will be it automatic or manual. Testing only verifies that they were implemented correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think that the assumption in the post @DZone has a fundamental issue. I think they are mixing DTOs (JPA) with the "live" objects in their application model.

The Entity going into or being retrieved via JPA is a DTO @Value object and not a @Data Object.

An application should map it's "application model" to the externalized DTOs, regardless if they are a "REST DTO" or a "JPA DTO".

For a JPA get and save to compare changes, you shouldn't simply change the fields in the DTO, because that is not what the database knows.

Comment: So, am I right you mean that for REST DTO we shoukd use @Data (we OK with generation by lombok using all fields in class). And for JPA DTO we should use in equals only PK and some constant in hashcode?